# A condition such that $p\mid\sum_{f(\theta)=0}\theta^n$ for all $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $f$ is any monic polynomial/$\mathbb{Z}$ with non-zero constant coefficient. I wish to study the quantities

$$t_n=\sum_{i}\theta_i^n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

where $(\theta_i)_{i=1}^{d}$ are the roots of $f$ counted with multiplicity.

The main question I am interested is finding all the primes $p$ such that $p\mid t_n$ for all large enough $n$. I have proved that this can only happen in the case that either $p\mid c_n$  $\forall$ $n$ where $c_n$ are the non-leading coefficients of $f$, or $p\mid t_n$ $\forall$ $n\geq0$.

The condition that $p\mid c_n$ is easy to check, so my interest has turned to some algebraic interpretation of the condition that $p\mid t_n$ for all $n$. My current idea is to let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta_i)_{i=1}^{d}$ be the field attached to $f$, and analyse the ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ generated by $(\theta_i)_{i=1}^{d}$. My idea is that it seems as if $p\mid t_n$ $\forall$ $n$ implies that any element of $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ will be a multiple of $p$. The converse is obvious.

Is the above observation correct? If so, is there some known property of such primes (i.e. $I\cap \mathbb{Z} \subset p\mathbb{Z}$ iff $p$ ramifies in $\mathcal{O}_K$)?

Comment: The observation you propose, that $p \mid t_{n}$ for all $n$ implies that every element of $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a multiple of $p$, isn't true. For example, if $\theta_{1} = 1$, $\theta_{2} = 4$ and $\theta_{3} = 7$, then $3 \mid t_{n}$ for all $n$, but $\langle \theta_{1}, \theta_{2}, \theta_{3} \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ contains many elements that are not multiples of $3$.

Comment: @JeremyRouse Thank you so much for the example!

Comment: It seems that you are counting the roots without multiplicity. Is it obvious why this should be the right approach? \\ Also, TeX note: please use $p \mid t$ `p \mid t`, not $p | t$ `p | t`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Sorry I meant that the roots should be counted with multiplicity; I totally see how that wasn't clear. I will use $p\mid t$ in the future, thanks for the note!

Comment: @JeremyRouse I think I see where the failure in my intuition was. My idea is that if you have an element of $I\cap \mathbb{Z}$ you can "symmetrize" by adding all permutations of the roots, and then that should be reducible with the $t_k$ which are all multiples of $p$ so every element of $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a multiple of $p$. The problem is, when you symmetrize you multiply by a factor of $d!$ so this argument does not work when $p|d$ and thus the intuition is moot.

Comment: It seems you are assuming implicitly that, say, $f$ has integer coefficients (otherwise, why would $t_n$ be in $\mathbb{Z}$?) At least for $p>\deg f$ the condition $p \mid t_n$ for all $n$ is the same as $p \mid c_n$ for $0 \le n < \deg f$. Indeed, the coefficients of $f$ are polynomials (with rational coefficients having denominator dividing $\deg f!$) in $t_1,\ldots,t_{\deg f}$; see Newton-Girard identities for explicit formulas for these. If $p>\deg f$ the denominators shouldn't worry us.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky, I thought that it was clear that $f$ had integer coefficients from when I said it was monic but the question has been changed for clarity. In my main paragraph I clearly state that I already know that either $p\mid t_n$ implies either $p\mid c_n$ for all $n<\deg(f)$ or $p \mid t_n$ for all $n$. Implicit in this is that the condition is equivalent to  $p\mid c_n$ for $p>\deg(f)$ since $t_0=\deg(f)$. I am well aware of Newton's formulas and I used them in my proof.

Comment: @MiloMoses So why not just change $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ in the first line?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly, Generally my preference is to define polynomials over fields instead of rings, but I totally see how that is confusing. It has been edited once again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have $t_k=0$ for all $k$ if and only if $f(x) \bmod p$ is a $p$-th power.

Let $g(x)$ be the image of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$; let $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, ..., $\alpha_n$ be the roots of $g$ (with multiplicity) in $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, let $e_k$ be the $k$-th elementary symmetric function in the roots, and let $p_k = \sum \alpha_i^k$. You want a criterion for when all the $p_k$ are $0$.

If each $\alpha_i$ occurs with multiplicity divisible by $p$ then, clearly, $p_k=0$.

Conversely, suppose all the $p_k$ are $0$. Then, by Newton's identities, $k e_k = 0$ for all $k$. So, whenever $p$ does not divide $k$, we have $e_k=0$. But this means that the coefficient of $x^{(\deg g(x))-k}$ in $g(x)$ vanishes whenever $p$ does not divide $x$, so $g(x)$ is of the form $h(x^p) x^m$, where $m$ is equivalent mod $p$ to the degree of $g$. Since you imposed that $p_0=0$ as well, the degree of $g(x)$ is $0 \bmod p$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the kind of criterion I was looking for, splendidly simple proof.

Comment: It's not the greatest idea to be using characteristic $p$ and also writing power sums as $p_k$.  Maybe $P_k$?

Comment: Reading closer, you seem to be using without proof that $t_k \mod{p}=p_k$. This is trivial if we assume that the reduction-mod-$p$ map extends to a full ring homomorphism from the ring of algebraic integers to to $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, but I don't see how it is so clear without that assumption. I know that this extension be done (see here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897660/extending-homomorphism-into-algebraically-closed-field), but I think that you should make it more clear what is happening inside of your answer.